# What are the basic steps to connect to Facebook from an Android application?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I can't find any specific solution for connecting to Facebook from an Android app. Can I get basic code to connect my application to Facebook?

I have an app id and API key. How do I find an access token and where do I use it?

Comment: Please delete this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Google: [Link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android)

Answer (score 0):

First, grab the SDK:
[Facebook Android SDK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk)

Then, take a look at the great getting started guide:[Getting started guide for Facebook Android SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/#android)

You'll be up in no time :)